# How do I highlight parentheses whenever the cursor is inside?

Tags: vim, match, syntax-highlighting, parentheses

I'd like to highlight the enclosing parentheses whenever the cursor is inside them.  How do I do that in Vim?  The plugins that I can find with Google only highlight the match when the cursor is on the parenthesis itself, so I can't use those to solve my problem. I cannot figure out a good regular expression to use to account for nesting, so syntax highlighting definitions don't seem like a good approach.

Comment: Are you searching for a plugin (such recommendations are off-topic here), or do you plan to implement such yourself? For the latter, what have you tried so far?!

Comment: This is not off-topic because it requires Vimscript, a programming language in itself. I am not specifically looking for plugin recommendations, but if someone provides, I'd appreciate it. I have not attempted to implement this myself because it requires pattern matching (regex?) for which I have zero knowledge and zero time to learn at the moment. Please reopen.

Comment: The question is not asking for an offsite resource; it's asking how to solve a particular problem in Vim.  While the OP clearly hasn't done any research (as evidenced by their comment). That's a reason to downvote this question, but not a reason to close it.  If the OP were asking for a plugin, then it'd be an off topic question. Note that a plugin could be on-topic as an answer; and that's ok. It's the explicit asking for off-site resources that's the issue. [This question is a topic of meta discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253055/b/253057#253057).

Comment: As far as closing because there isn't minimal information to diagnose the 'problem'. The OP hasn't asked for their code to be debugged (a problem to be fixed), they're asking for code to do something in VimScript. Downvote if you feel it doesn't show any research effort, but because this question doesn't have to do with already written code, that close reason doesn't really apply here.

Answer (score 7):

Properly matching a pair of parentheses, with an arbitrary number of nested pairs inside, is not a solvable problem using regular expressions alone. Limiting the problem by limiting the number of allowed nestings results in very ugly regular expressions. So don't try going that route.

Luckily, Vim provides a `searchpairpos()` function to find such pairs accounting for nesting.

See the example in Vim at `:help match-parens` for an example on using searchpairpos() to highlight the parenthesis which matches the one under your cursor. You should be able to extend it to first search for the next parenthesis before or after the cursor to use as a starting point for the matched pair.

Comment: Thank you. You may have observed the negative atmosphere around this question. Without your answer it would never had occurred to me that I could use `searchpairpos()` to determine ranges of text enclosed in parentheses.